# Request Product in Store Kit not working

Tags: javascript, iphone, in-app-purchase, titanium, storekit

Hi I am using store kit in titanium.I am using this code

```
 Ti.App.storekit=require('ti.storekit');
   Ti.App.storekit.requestProduct('553XXXXXX.testproductname', function (product) {
    var buySingleItem = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: 'Buy ' + product.title + ', ' + product.formattedPrice,
        top: 60, left: 5, right: 5, height: 40
    });
    buySingleItem.addEventListener('click', function () {
        purchaseProduct(product);
    });
    HomeWin.add(buySingleItem);
});
```

But it is giving me error that it is undefined and not a function Can somebody help me about this Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never inject a module in to the Titanium namespace. It will be garbage collected unexpectedly. You will run in to this, sooner or later, so change it now.

Also, it's "requestProducts", not "requestProduct" (should be plural).

Look back at the example included with the module and its documentation. This is all laid out there.

```
var Storekit = require('ti.storekit');
Storekit.requestProducts([ '553XXXXXX.testproductname' ], function (evt) {
    if (!evt.success) {
        alert('ERROR: We were not able to get the product!');
    }
    else if (evt.invalid) {
        alert('ERROR: We requested an invalid product!');
    }
    else {
        alert(evt.products[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi i have added the module in Tiapp.xml and i have downloaded it form the same marketplace.The problem is that Module is being detected but it is just that it is not recognizing its function Thanks

Comment: You cannot inject it in to the Titanium.App module. It will not be defined. Or, if you try to inject it in Titanium, it will be garbage collected unexpextedly. Your problem is as I stated, "never inject a module in to the Titanium namespace". Take it out of there. Do a normal var Storekit = require, as the example does.

Comment: Edited to also point out that it's requestProducts, with an "S".